# notifyDataSetChanged() not called with stickygridheadersbaseadapter

Tags: android, baseadapter, contentobserver, notifydatasetchanged

I have an fragment in which I am using a ContentObserver class which notifies me of any change in my database table.

In an Asynctask I retrieve the data from the database and add it to the adapter.
Then on using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() does not refresh the gridView though on proper debugging I am able to see the updated data in the arraylist but on the UI.

//My Adapter class

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
    StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Assignment> assignmentsGlobalData;

public ArrayList<Assignment> getAssignmentsGlobalData() {
    return assignmentsGlobalData;
}

private ArrayList<Section> sectionList;

private Context mContext;

public int getAssignmentsGlobalDataLength() {
    return assignmentsGlobalData.size();
}

private boolean isOtherUser;
private UserObject userObj;

int selectedPosition = -1;

public void setSelected(int setPosition) {
    this.selectedPosition = setPosition;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public MyCustomAdapter (boolean isOtherUser, UserObject userObj,
        Context mContext) {

    this.assignmentsGlobalData = new ArrayList<Assignment>();
    this.sectionList = new ArrayList<AllAssignment.Section>();
    this.isOtherUser = isOtherUser;
    this.userObj = userObj;
    this.mContext = mContext;

}

public void putData(ArrayList<Section> list,
        ArrayList<Assignment> assignments) {
    this.sectionList.clear();
    this.sectionList.addAll(list);
    this.assignmentsGlobalData.clear();
    this.assignmentsGlobalData.addAll(assignments);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void addData(ArrayList<Assignment> assignments,
        ArrayList<Section> sectionList) {
    this.assignmentsGlobalData = assignments;
    this.sectionList = sectionList;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return assignmentsGlobalData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return assignmentsGlobalData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((LayoutInflater) FinoitKit.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.new_assignment_item, null);
    }
   //I do my usual work here..
return convertView;

}
@Override
public int getCountForHeader(int header) {

    if (sectionList.size() > 0)
        return sectionList.get(header).num;
    else
        return 0;

}

@Override
public int getNumHeaders() {
    return sectionList.size();
}

public void putSectionList(ArrayList<Section> list) {
    this.sectionList = list;
}

@Override
public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((LayoutInflater) FinoitKit.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.assignment_section_view, parent, false);
    }
    TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_date);
    date.setText(sectionList.get(position).date);

    return convertView;

}
```

//My AsyncTask for loading updated content from database

```
private class LoadAssignmnets extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Assignment>> {
    boolean isFilterChanged;

    public LoadAssignmnets(boolean isFilterChanged) {
        this.isFilterChanged = isFilterChanged;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        isLoading = true;
        setRefreshActionButtonState(true);
        if (isFilterChanged)
            showAssignmentGridLoadingView();

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Assignment> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Cursor cursor = AllAssignment.getInstance().loadAssignments(
                mContext,
                AllAssignment.getInstance().getStatusBundle(
                        AllAssignment.ALL, gradeObj, userObj, assignedBy));

        ArrayList<Assignment> assignment = new ArrayList<Assignment>();
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                assignment.add(new Assignment(cursor));
            }
            cursor.close();

        }

        return assignment;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Assignment> result) {
        isLoading = false;
        if (result.size() > 0) {
            assignments = result;
            assignmentAdaper.putData(AllAssignment.getInstance()
                    .getHeaderCount(result), result);

            if (isFragmentAlive)
                showAssignmentGridView();

        } else {
            showAssignmentEmptyGridView();


        }

        setRefreshActionButtonState(false);

    };

}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: your adapter yet not updated. Because if you receive notify, you have to retrieve the updated values from the database. After that you have to refresh it.

Comment: Yes,I did that.I have written it above also.

Comment: ok, share your code for retrieve updated value